# Using Nuxt.js project both with or without electron

Tags: electron, nuxt.js

I would like to configure a Nuxt.js project to be able to eitheir run it using `nuxt start` or using electron. The goal is to have the same code for a web app and an electron app.

Is it possible to combine both fontionnalities in the same project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nuxt Community already have an `electron-template` for make it happen.
You can take a look at [main.js](https://github.com/nuxt-community/electron-template/blob/master/template/main.js) file to see the configuration or just init a project using:

`vue init nuxt-community/electron-template my-project`

Link: https://github.com/nuxt-community/electron-template

Answer (score 2):

Nuxt Community template is out of updates.use the following boilerplate for nuxt+electron

```
# Install vue-cli and scaffold boilerplate
npm install -g vue-cli
vue init michalzaq12/electron-nuxt <project-name>
```

Link: https://github.com/michalzaq12/electron-nuxt